# Cant send subject in email - python

Tags: python, django

when i send an email message like this i cant get the subject get into the message(i get it in the body). what can i do to change it? thank you!

```
def SendEmailNotHTML(EmailToList,EmailBody,EmailSubject):

mail_from = settings.SMTP_USER
try:
    for current_mail_to in EmailToList:
        fromaddr = settings.SMTP_USER
        toaddrs  = current_mail_to
        msg = "\r\n".join([
        "Subject: {0}".format(EmailSubject),
        "",
        "{0}".format(EmailBody)
        ])
        print(msg)
        my_email = MIMEText(msg, "plain")
        username = settings.SMTP_USER
        password = settings.SMTP_PASSWORD
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:25')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username,password)
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, my_email.as_string())
        server.quit()
except Exception as e:
    print('cant send email' + str(e))
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do not use Django's email backend?

Comment: there are some specific ways in django that you can send emails in djano. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/ refer this